# monitor file changes in c++ (windows)

Tags: c++, windows, file, monitoring, filesystemwatcher

I have a set of files and I would like to monitor them for changes.
I have tried FileSystemWatcher class, but it seems notifications are fired after file is changed and then saved. Say, if I monitor directory for changes in .txt files, open some file, save it FileSystemWatcher works. But how can I monitor changes when the file is opened and something is typed without saving? Reading original first and then reading the same file after some interval and then comparing them seems slow and stupid. Is there a nice way to monitor such situation?

Comment: The only event you will receive is modified on close.

Comment: Why would reading the same file after some interval have any different effect than using `FileSystemWatcher`...

Comment: @EdwardThomson: It could make a difference for applications that are writing to disk without closing the file, e.g. a database, or a long duration log file.

Comment: @YpsilonIV: What you're describing isn't a file change.

Comment: Drew Dormann, so what is it and how can I deal with it?

Comment: @YpsilonIV: You can't. If an application wants to read a file and modify the data it read, you will not and cannot know about it.

Comment: @Ypsilon  That's the point, you can't deal with it.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Fair point, however I'm pretty sure that `FileSystemWatcher` will notify you as soon as `FlushFileBuffers()` is called (not on `Close()`) which means that caching may affect the timeliness of `FileSystemWatcher` events.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, because the file itself hasn't changed yet.

Answer (score 3):

No, if you read a file into memory and modifies it, how would another application know about it?